# How to simulate the transcription result with pytest without actually sending data to Azure Speech API

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I'm having trouble coming up with a pytest function to test the function below:

Is there a way to mock any function/object such that I can fake a transcription result that's consistent every time I run the test and not send any data to the actual Azure Speech service (so it doesn't get billed)?

```
def transcribe_azure_speech_file(speech_file):
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=SUBSCRIPTION_KEY, region=REGION)
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename=speech_file)
    auto_source_lang_config = speechsdk.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig(languages=["en-US"])
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(
        speech_config=speech_config,
        audio_config=audio_input,
        auto_detect_source_language_config=auto_source_lang_config
    )

    transcripts = []
    done = False

    def _stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    def _recognized_event(evt):
        result = evt.result
        start_time = result.offset / 10e6
        end_time = start_time + result.duration / 10e6

        transcripts.append(
            {
                "transcript": result.text,
                "start_time": start_time,
                "end_time": end_time,
            }
        )

    # connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(_recognized_event)
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(_stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(_stop_cb)

    # start continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(0.25)

    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()

    return transcripts
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not get billed for calling Azure Speech API, just create a free tier service (F0 plan):

[image]